# Information in Feed Weebhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I subscribed to feed webhook and I ve receiving posts everytime the user navigate and search something.

Is the expected behavior because documentation say:
Describes changes to most sections of the user's profile, such as About, Photos, Posts, Friends, and Likes

The json that I receive is:

```
{
    "entry": 
    [
        {
            "time": 542196889466880, 
            "id": "0", 
            "changed_fields": ["feed"], 
            "uid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

        }], 
        "object": "user"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide JSON of Facebook you receive when the user navigate and search something?
I'm using webhook. I've only subscribed to webhook feed, and I only receive event data when user comment/post/reaction in my page.

Comment: I edited the question. The only thing is that I subscribed to user, not to page.